# Socket closed by remote peer Error when server disconnected in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

I am using GCDAsyncSocket for connecting to socket. App works fine till phone gets lock.
When phone gets unlock then **socketDidDisconnect** gets call with error (**Socket closed by remote peer**). there I am reconnecting to server but socket gets disconnected every time. Is there any way to reconnect to socket?

Here is my **Code** :

```
-(void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{

NSLog(@"Socket Disconnected===== %@",err);

[self serverConnection];

}

-(void)serverConnection
{

  asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc]initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];


NSError *err = nil;
if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:ipAddress onPort:portNumber error:&err]){

    NSLog(@"Error in acceptOnPort:error: -> %@", err);

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Socket Connecting");
}


}
```

Comment: Did you got the solution?